# The 2D array won't transponse c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a simple task to transponse a square 2D array:
(I need to do it in a very plain manner, no containers etc)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        double[,] a = new double[5, 5];
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                a[i, j] = random.NextDouble();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(a[i, j] + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                double temp = a[i, j];
                a[i, j] = a[j, i];
                a[j, i] = temp;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(a[i, j] + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

I was expecting a reversed array as the output. However, I got the same array here. Please, help me find out what did I do wrong?
[image: Console output. The double array won't transponse]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you are executing both `for` loops from `0` to `5`. So you are doing the transpose twice.

For example, for `i=0` and `j=1` you transpose `a[0,1]` with `a[1,0]` and when `i=1` and `j=0` the values of `a[1,0]` and `a[0,1]` going back to its original position.

You can make the inner `for` from `0` to `i`, so the positions are swapped just one time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        double temp = a[i, j];
        a[i, j] = a[j, i];
        a[j, i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The third loop swaps both diagonal halves of the array, you have to swap only the elements from one half:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        double temp = a[i, j];
        a[i, j] = a[j, i];
        a[j, i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your swapping loop you need to change the inner loop limit to avoid the double swap problem. Change: 
`for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)` 
to 
`for(j = 0; j < i; j++)`